Define loss streaks based on win streaks (complex mutation logic help)
I have a data frame (df0) with win streaks, e.g.:
> df0
   player win_streak
1   id_p1          1
2   id_p2          1
3   id_p1          1
4   id_p1          2
5   id_p1          3
6   id_p1          4
7   id_p2          1
8   id_p2          2
9   id_p1          1
10  id_p2          1

Players compete, and each row contains the winning player of a round. win_streak adds up the number of consecutive wins for a given player.
I now want to get the loss_streak for each player that repeats the maximum win_streak value from the opponent's most recent win_streak repeated for all rows in the current winner's win_streak.
For example, the current df would turn into:
   player win_streak loss_streak
1   id_p1          1          NA
2   id_p2          1           1
3   id_p1          1           1
4   id_p1          2           1
5   id_p1          3           1
6   id_p1          4           1
7   id_p2          1           4
8   id_p2          2           4
9   id_p1          1           2
10  id_p2          1           1


Data:
df0 = structure(list(player = c("id_p1", "id_p2", "id_p1", "id_p1", 
"id_p1", "id_p1", "id_p2", "id_p2", "id_p1", "id_p2"), win_streak = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")


that is what I am asking... maybe the fact this is a question is not clear. I will update

I am trying to get a value for each row representing the number of rounds the current winner lost during their last loss streak. The point of this, if that is what you're asking, is for statistical modelling alone side omitted variables.

I am not looking for a sequence(rle(stack_df$player)$lengths) for loss streak. I want the length of the previous loss streak of the player of interest for the row (i.e., the last number of the win streak from the other players previous  sequence(rle(stack_df$player)$lengths)). I gave an example of what this would look like in the question.

1) Define a loss_streak function which assigns a unique consecutive number in vector r to each streak and then looks up the index of the prior streak using findInterval, replaces 0 with NA and indexes win_streak with that.
library (dplyr)

loss_streak <- function(player, win_streak) {
  r <- consecutive_id(player)
  win_streak[na_if(findInterval(r-1, r), 0)]
}

df0 %>%
  mutate(loss_streak = loss_streak(player, win_streak))

giving
   player win_streak loss_streak
1   id_p1          1          NA
2   id_p2          1           1
3   id_p1          1           1
4   id_p1          2           1
5   id_p1          3           1
6   id_p1          4           1
7   id_p2          1           4
8   id_p2          2           4
9   id_p1          1           2
10  id_p2          1           1

2) We can also create a base R version of the above by defining rle_id which is like consecutive_id in dplyr and zero2na which replaces 0's with NA.
rle_id <- function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))

zero2na <- function(x) replace(x, x == 0, NA)

loss_streak2 <- function(player, win_streak) {
  r <- rle_id(player)
  win_streak[zero2na(findInterval(r-1, r))]
}

df0 |>
   transform(loss_streak = loss_streak2(player, win_streak))

Note
df0 <- data.frame(player = c("id_p1", "id_p2", "id_p1", "id_p1", "id_p1", "id_p1", 
    "id_p2", "id_p2", "id_p1", "id_p2"),
  win_streak = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)
)

